# One to Many relation in the same MongoDB collection related query

Tags: java, mongodb, one-to-many, micronaut, micronaut-data

What would be the best approach to implement below use case in MICRONAUT DATA mongoDB

The use case:
One to Many mapping in the same collection

[IMAGE SHOWING THE USECASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hnWX.png)

The element collection is used to store elements of different types. Area, points, segments etc.
So for e.g. Area can have multiple childs - points, segments etc

The document will have full element details and selective child details with full hierarchy.
The child will be present in database independently as well with complete details.

Any update/delete/create to the element will require the changes to be propageted to the parent & child elements respectively.

Would we also require mapping annotation usage between parent and child?

ENTITY

```
@MappedEntity
public class Element{
  @Id
  @AutoPopulated
  private UUID id;
  @NotNull
  private ElementType elementType;
  @NotNull
  private String name;
  @NotNull
  private PointGeoJson pointGeometry;
  @Nullable
  private Set<Element> associations;
  ... other attributes ...
}
```

PARENT

```
{
  "id": "a581edd0-ee62-4b1d-b02a-5e3b68f7b234",
  "elementType": "PARKING_AREA",
  "name": "Area Element",
  "pointGeometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      37.7749,
      -122.4194
    ]
  },
  "associations": [
    {
      "id": "b581edd0-ee62-4b1d-b02a-5e3b68f7b235",
      "elementType": "POINT"
    },
    {
      "id": "c581edd0-ee62-4b1d-b02a-5e3b68f7b236",
      "elementType": "POINT"
      }
    }
  ],
  ... other attributes ...
}
```

CHILD

```
{
  "id": "b581edd0-ee62-4b1d-b02a-5e3b68f7b235",
  "elementType": "POINT",
  "name": "Point Element",
  "pointGeometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      37.7749,
      -122.4194
    ]
  },
  "associations": null,
  ... other attributes ...
}
```

Do we require any annotation usages for mapping between 2 elements or is it not required?